# Wordpress - Get all users who commented on a post

Tags: wordpress

I need to get all users who commented on a post. And for each user the comments. Searched online but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

If    post_id= 15 then

```
 <?php 
    $comments = get_comments('post_id=15');
    foreach($comments as $comment) :

        echo($comment->comment_author .'--coment--'.$comment->comment_content);
        echo '<br>';
    endforeach;
    ?>
```

see this for further details https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments

.

Comment: how would i group those by user? now i have 2 comments by the same user and it's showing me `user1user1`

Comment: Please check my answer now . it show both comment author name and comment  .

Answer (score 0):

You can get comment writer from its comment id:

```
<?php $author = get_comment_author( $comment_ID ); ?>
```

You can generate short code use it, Here this will display all information of comment.You need to extract which one is required.

```
 function input_func( $atts ) {
        global $post;
         $comments = get_comments( array( 'number' => 2, 'post_id' => get_the_ID() ) );
         print_r( $comments);
    }
    add_shortcode( 'input', 'input_func' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [get_comments()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments).

Here is how you get all comments on a certain post:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'post_id' => 0, // Place post ID here.
    );
get_comments( $args ); 
?>
```

After running this code, you will get an array of posts and user IDs, you can use the IDs with a foreach to get all comments for each user. Like this:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
'user_id' => 0, // Place user ID here.
);
get_comments( $args ); 
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Code:**

```
 global $wpdb, $post;
 // Query
 $query = sprintf("SELECT comment_author_email
                   FROM {$wpdb->comments}
                   JOIN {$wpdb->posts} ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->comments}.comment_post_ID
                   WHERE comment_post_ID = %d AND comment_approved = '1'", 
                   $post->ID);
 $emailslist = $wpdb->get_col($query);
 $emailslist = array_unique($emailslist);

 // get all emails
 print_r($emailslist);
```

Here you can get list of emails of users.

You can also use `WP_Comment_Query`